# Числительные с прилагательным

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Две спелых груши" или "две спелые груши"?
"Три больших ягоды" или "три большие ягоды"?

*"Два сладких яблока" или "Четыре полосатых арбуза" сомнений почему-то не порождают.*

Вопрос возник, когда я задумался над сочетанием "две ничьи (игры)". Может, и тут надо "две ничьих"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается фруктов (в вашем вопросе), то есть правило. При существительных *мужского* и *среднего* рода, зависящих от числительных **два, три, четыре** (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме *родительного* падежа множественного числа. Поэтому с яблоками и арбузами у вас проблем не возникло: *два сладких яблока, четыре полосатых арбуза.*  При существительных *женского* рода в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится в форме *именительного* падежа (или совпадающего с ним винительного при неодушевленных существительных) множественного числа. Поэтому правильно будет так: *две спелые груши, три большие ягоды.*
Более подробно об этом можно почитать, например, у Розенталя.

Теперь относительно слова НИЧЬЯ. В орфографическом словаре читаем: "Ничья, ничьей, мн. ничьи, -ьих, сущ." Существительное, но не настоящее, а "превращенное": было местоимение-прилагательное, стало существительное. Приведенное выше правило требует от прилагательного формы именительного падежа множественного числа. Следовательно, нужно писать **две ничьи**.

Comment: >>>Более подробно об этом можно почитать, например, у Розенталя  
Точную ссылку не дадите? Я с Розенталем в обем-то дружу, такого не помню. 

Что касается "ничьи".

Comment: Что касается "ничьи".

>>>поэтому в сочетании с числительными должно иметь форму падежа и числа, как существительные.  
нет. Это субстантиват, сохраняющий форму прилагательных. Будь по вашему, было бы именно две ничьи, как две свиньи, попадьи.

>>>Числительные два, три, четыре требуют после себя формы родительного падежа единственного числа.

Нет. Это историческая форма двойственного числа, в большинстве случаев совпавшая с **родительным единственного**. А вы предлагаете **родительный множественного**.

Answer (score 1):

две спелые груши.
две высоких горы.
-их в случае отличия существительного во множественном числе и в ед.числе родительного падежа.

Comment: Никто не должен начинать писать со строчной. Редактор вам в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я нашел в "Справке" на Грамоте.

Вопрос № 201982 
Здравствуйте, уважаемое "Справочное бюро"! Скажите, пожалуйста, в какой форме должно стоять существительное "ничья", управляемое числительными два, три, четыре в именительном и винительном падежах: две ничьих или две ничьи? Спасибо!
Авхутская Т. В.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Корректны оба варианта. на выбор формы влияет форма сказуемого; ср.: *Были зафиксированы две ничьи. -- Было зафиксировано две ничьих*.

Но что-то подсказывает, что это не вся правда. Скорее уж сказуемое выбирается по выбранной форме. Да и обоснования нет.

Comment: Да, все правильно, "две ничьи". Но мне и "две ничьих" тоже нравится. Отвлеклась на минуту - и вот, налепила ошибок. Исправляюсь! А по поводу сказуемого Розенталь пишет, что форма сказуемого МОЖЕТ оказать влияние на выбор формы определения. Ну, и о двойственном числе я не упоминаю, поскольку в современном языке его нет, не хочется запутывать вопрошающих. Спасибо!