# "41 разрешимая и 93 неразрешимые задачи" - как правильно?

Tags: склонение

> «Было выделено 441 разрешимая и 93 неразрешимые задачи.»

интересует написание слов разрешимая и неразрешимые.

Answer (score 1):

Варианта только два.
*Были выделены 441 разрешимая и 93 неразрешимые задачи.*
*Были выделены 441 разрешимая и 93 неразрешимых задачи.*

"Неразрешимые" однозначно слитно. А вот касательно падежной формы...
Прилагательные (и причастия, чтобы избежать спора) женского рода при числительных на "две", "три", "четыре" обычно имеют форуму именительного-винительного падежа. Обсуждали тут: [Числительные с прилагательным](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5255) .

Однако это правило рекомендательное, можно и отступить. А поскольку первая часть имеет управление в форме числа единственного, для лучшего восприятия второй вариант кажется мне более удачным.

Answer (score -1):

Предлгается следующий вариант решения:

Были выделены 441 разрешимая и 93 неразрешимые задачи.

93 неразрешимые задачи - здесь согласование в И.п. для сущ. ж.рода. Сказуемое лучше использовать  в форме мн. числа (были выделены задачи).

Сравнить: Было выделено 441 разрешимый и 93 неразрешимых вопросов (согласование в Р.п. для сущ. м.рода, здесь можно оставить форму ед.числа для сказуемого).

Comment: Вопрос-то не в этом, а в словах "разрешимая" и "неразрешимые".

Comment: Вашим  комментариям не хватает ясности, они сокращены до предела и вследствие этого часто содержат нулевую информацию (намеки, а не высказывания). Вот и в данном вопросе всё то же самое. Здесь должны решаться две задачи: выбор формы сказуемого (ед. или мн. число) и выбор Р.п. или И.п. для второго прилагательного. Для выбора формы прилагательного есть определенное  (обоснованное) решение: если с точностью до ударения совпадают две формы сущ. ж.р.  (задачи  (И.п. мн. ч.) и нет задачи (Р.п. ед.ч), то прилагательное используется в форме И.п.

Comment: Почему? Да потому что в русском языке есть действует правило сочетаемости стоящих РЯДОМ слов, поэтому именно эта форма предпочтительнее, лучше воспринимается на слух. Что касается формы сказуемого, то она у Вас не рассматривается вовсе, а зря,  так как здесь тоже возможно два решения, на выбор которых влияют разные факторы, в частности, препозиция сказуемого, с одной стороны, и согласование с "неразрешимые задачи", с другой стороны. Поэтому Ваше решение мне  не кажется безупречным. Минуса я не ставлю, но, надеюсь, что объяснение понятно.